# Color and Graphic fill in SLD geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to add two overlays in `<Fill>` tag.

For example, I want to add this color, **#1e9e1e**, and a graphic fill. **xlink:href="vegetation.png"**.

This is my code:

`<Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#1e9e1e</CssParameter>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="vegetation.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>15</Size>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>

            </Fill>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add another PolygonSymbolizer tag inside a rule:

```
<Rule>
    <PolygonSymbolizer>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#1e9e1e</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
  <Stroke>
    <CssParameter name="stroke">#afb38a</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</CssParameter>
  </Stroke>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
<PolygonSymbolizer>
  <Fill>
      <GraphicFill>
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="vegetation.png"/>
            <Format>image/png</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <Size>15</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </GraphicFill>
    </Fill>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

It should work.